# How can I filter for specific criteria, get all non-empty columns and their contents then transpose?

Tags: jquery, arrays, google-sheets, transpose

I was wondering if there is a more efficient of writing the code below (which is currently in 3 different tabs).

My first tab is a form response.
Second tab is to filter criteria
Third tab is to remove any empty columns.
Fourth tab is the response from tab 3 transposed.

Can I do all this in one tab. I have a lot of criteria to filter and this way will take me a long time.

```
=QUERY({'Form responses 1'!A1:EV},"select * where Col3 ='Inbound'",1) 

=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(IF('Inbound Filter'!A2:A<>"", "♠"&'Inbound Filter'!A2:A&"♦"&IF('Inbound Filter'!B2:EV<>"",'Inbound Filter'!B2:EV, "♥")&"♦"&'Inbound Filter'!B1:EV1, )), "♠")), "♦"),   "select Col1,max(Col2) where Col2 <> '♥' group by Col1 pivot Col3"))

=TRANSPOSE('Inbound Data'!A1:BZ)
```

Comment: I have a formulaic method do do this all in one formula, but would need a sample sheet to demonstrate on.  Could you share an editable sheet here so I can demo the solution?

Comment: Have you considered doing this with Apps Script?

Comment: Hi Matt. I have attached a copy. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1P1zNwKF1Tu19w4yJJiI1rp4wfXhcFGnU45CGChwnyyg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi Jescanellas. I do not know how to do apps scripts for this level of what I need. I have put in a copy if there is a way you can have a go.

Comment: Hi Alon. Your solution is really good. I have tried to expand the search however it is coming up with  this error:  Text result of CONCATENATE is longer than the limit of 50000 characters.             =(ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(concat(CONCATENATE(IF('Replenishment Filter'!A1:A<>"", "♠"&'Replenishment Filter'!A1:A&"♦"&IF('Replenishment Filter'!B2:JA<>"",'Replenishment Filter'!B2:JA, "♥")&"♦"&'Replenishment Filter'!B1:JA1, )), "♠")), "♦"), "select Col1,max(Col2) where Col2 <> '♥' group by Col1 pivot Col3")))